# Photoshop: How to remove vertical teal lines?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I just received a design from a designer and I opened it in photoshop but there are teal vertical lines. How do I remove them?[image]

Comment: They are guides. You can remove them from the top menu `View > Clear guides` or you can also just hide them `View > Show > Guides`.

Comment: Or, for the shortcut: CTRL + H should work:)

Comment: @joonas that's an answer :) Not sure what else anyone could possibly post :)

Comment: @joonas I think it's more likely someone has drawn lines with a teal stroke onto the page, I must remember to do that next time I have to send artwork! :)

Comment: @mayersdesign [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl20I.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl20I.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to delete it off your illustrator file, right-click on the teal guideline, select "Release guides", then continue with on the select other lines and hit "Delete" button.

Or if you simply wish to hide it, just press Ctrl + ; (for windows).

Comment: I always use control+h... is there a difference?

Comment: @mayersdesign `Ctrl+;`is a shortcut for toggling the visibility of guides specifically, whereas `Ctrl+H` is a shortcut for toggling the visibility of "extras". The "extras" covers everything under `View > Show`: Guides, Grid, Pixel grid, etc...

Comment: This answer is correct but the first paragraph is specifically for Adobe Illustrator. Perhaps you could edit your answer to better state that and then also say how to do it in Adobe Photoshop which is the software Edmund is using.